# What currency does inter government debt take place?

Tags: foreign-exchange, debt, international

For example If japan borrows from china what currency will it borrow in ?Or if India borrows from Russia what currency will the debt take place in ?

Answer (score 4):

Such debts are issued through bonds.  The entity that issues the bond determines the currency in which it is valued and paid.